# mySQL - Summing rows based on a flag

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I'm summing a few million rows and it looks roughly like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(FlagColumn = 1, dollars, 0)) as booked,
    SUM(IF(FlagColumn = 0, dollars, 0)) as billed
FROM
   records
WHERE
   processedDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Was hoping someone could suggest a way to write this that may have better performance as this query is very slow. There's no way to break the `dollars` column out ahead of time, as the value of the flag column changes over time and therefore `dollars` gets reclassified over time.

Answer (score 1):

Build a composite index on your table:  `records(processedDate, flagcolumn, dollars)`.  This is the optimal index for the query.

Comment: Just FYI, OP...this kind of index is called covering index. Fields in this index will provide all information for your query and therefore the DB doesn't have to look at the table for information. Index is sufficient to retrieve information.

Comment: Oh, the engine optimises even field look up, not just order, from the index directly? This I did not know.

Comment: Think of an INDEX as another table -- sorted in a different way.  Think of a non-"covering" index as needing to find pointers in the INDEX, then reaching over into the "data", which is stored separately.  Think of a "covering" index as being able to do the entire query in the "table" (that is really an index).

Comment: It is usually important to have columns in a "compound" index (such as Gordon's) in the "right" order.  In this case, `processedDate` needs to be first in order to help with the `WHERE` clause.  The order of the other two fields does not matter (in this case).